# Filter array with an array of regex

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I am using Ruby 1.9.2p320 and running the following code snippet:

```
a = ["abc", "def", "pqr", "xyz"]
z = ["abc", "xyz"]
a.grep(/#{z}/)
```

That gives this output: `["abc", "xyz"]`.

```
a = ["abc_1", "def_1", "pqr_1", "xyz_1"]
z = ["abc_1", "xyz_1"]
a.grep(/#{z}/)
```

But this gives output as: `["abc_1", "def_1", "pqr_1", "xyz_1"]`.

What I expected was just `["abc_1", "xyz_1"]`.

Any particular reason why am i getting that output? And how could I get the expected output?

Comment: I tested with Ruby version 2.0.0p247. Same result. Not sure why it is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are building the regexp the wrong way, you should do something like:

```
a = ["abc_1", "def_1", "pqr_1", "xyz_1"]
z = ["abc_1", "xyz_1"]

a.grep(Regexp.union(z))
# => ["abc_1", "xyz_1"]
```

Your first example seems to work because `#{z}` is interpolated as the following expression:

```
/["abc", "xyz"]/
```

That is a [chararcters class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) that matches only against `"abc"` and `"xyz"`. In the second example `#{z}` is iterpolated as the following characters class:

```
/["abc_1", "xyz_1"]/
```

That matches all the strings in the array since they all include the character `1`.

Comment: I got my code snippet to work, but I didn't understand the explanation. Can you please elaborate or give me a reference or link. Thanks

Comment: I've added a link to the description of character classes, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a.grep(/#{z.join('|')}/)
# => ["abc_1", "xyz_1"]
```

It creates valid regexp - with regexp "or" statement - `/abc_1|xyz_1/`

Answer (score 2):

Both the answers above are perfectly fine as per your question.

but if you are working with arrays why not use `&` operator

```
a = ["abc_1", "def_1", "pqr_1", "xyz_1"]
z = ["abc_1", "xyz_1"]
a & z
=> ["abc_1", "xyz_1"]
```

same answer as using grep and simpler

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. I want to get a subset of an array with a specific prefix. In that case your method wont work.